# Should login and registration fragments and fragments when the user is logged in share the same activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I've got login fragments structure done, it looks like this:

```
LoginActivity:
    SignInFragment
    SignUpFragment
```

Now I want to program the fragments that user can see after they sign in. Let's say it's called `MainFragment` (I haven't come up with a name yet).

Should it have a separete activity:

```
MainActivity
   MainFragment
```

or I should have a one activity, let's stay with `MainActivity`, that will be shared among all fragments:

```
MainActivity
    SignInFragment
    SignUpFragment
    MainFragment
```

or it does it matter which method I choose?

Comment: Nowadays the most common approach is a single activity with multiple fragments. Read about Navigation Component. But if you don't use the navigation component the solution with multiple activities is also fine.

Comment: I do already use navigation component. Alright, so I'll do a single activity with multiple fragments. Thanks